# For given set of integers, find and count the pairs with maximum value of bitwise or

Tags: arrays, bit-manipulation

Let's say we have given set of integers $A = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots, x_n\}$, consisting of exactly $n$ values, all of them positive integers. Now the problem is to find the maximum value of bitwise or operation of all possible pairs $(x_i, x_j)$

We define bitwise or as bitwise operation that returns true if atleast one of the bits is turned on, in most programming languages it is declared as "|".

Edit: We assume that the numbers in the set can be written with at most 17 bits, or they are smaller than $2^{17}$.

For example, we have: $n=4, A = \{12, 3, 4, 11\}$ the maximum value of bitwise or will be $15$, because $12|3=15, 11|4=15, 12|11=15$ so the result is $15$ and we have exactly $3$ pairs that give this result.

**My thinking**

Obviously we can take each pair and see what is their bitwise or, but this leads us to solution in $O(N^2)$, and I think that there is much faster solution, I think that we don't need to calculate the bitwise or of all numbers, and we can only calculate it for some numbers.

Comment: Do you have any limit on the size of the numbers? For example, perhaps there are $O(\log n)$ bits long?

Comment: We can assume that the numbers will be less than $2^{17}$

Comment: This can help you: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-subarray-xor-in-a-given-array/

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you cite the source?  What else did you try, beyond noting that $O(N^2)$ is too slow? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems/practice problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: If the number of bits is fixed then this can be solved in $O(n)$. First determine how many of the possible words appears 0, 1, or at least 2 times. Given this information, look up the answer in a table. This shows that to make this problem interesting theoretically, you need to include the number of bits as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers have width $c\log n$ then there is a randomized $O(n^{2-1/O(\log c)})$ algorithm that finds the maximum OR correctly with high probability. The idea is to find the maximum OR bit by bit, MSB to LSB. We can do this using $c\log n$ queries of the following form: "Is there an OR whose $k$ most significant bits are $b_1\ldots b_k$?". Each such query is equivalent (up to bitwise operations) to the query (applied to a different list): "Is there an OR in which all bits are 1?". [Abboud, Williams, and Yu](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611973730.17) gave a randomized $O(n^{2-1/O(\log c)})$ time algorithm for this problem (which they call *Boolean orthogonal detection*, flipping 0s and 1s).

If the numbers have unbounded width then (depending on the exact model of computation), there is no $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ time algorithm (assuming SETH). Indeed, deciding whether the maximum OR is all 1s is the same as Boolean orthogonal detection, for which the aforementioned hardness is known (see for example [these lecture notes](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~russell/FGCA/lecture20.pdf) of Russel Impagliazzo).

Finally, if the numbers have bounded width then there is a simple $O(n)$ algorithm. The algorithm computes the set of numbers appearing in the input, and looks up the answer at a (rather large) table.

Comment: I edited the post, the numbers will be less than $2^{17}$

Comment: In that case, there is an $O(1)$ algorithm. See the last paragraph.

Comment: How do you create the lookup table, what do you keep in it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $O(n)$ algorithm. I create the lookup table in advance. I keep in it the answer for every set of inputs. This isn't a practical algorithm, though, since the lookup table is quite large.